# LIBLINEAR in C\C++

Tags: regression, libsvm, c++

I want to use LIBLINEAR (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear) directly in my C++ sources. While it seems simple using it in language like MATLAB/JAVA, in C seems very hard; for example, reading the README file, it seems that I have to transform every data matrix in a specific linked list format; from README

```
`x' is an array 
of pointers, each of which points to a sparse representation (array 
of feature_node) of one training vector.

For example, if we have the following training data:

LABEL       ATTR1   ATTR2   ATTR3   ATTR4   ATTR5
-----       -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
1           0       0.1     0.2     0       0
2           0       0.1     0.3    -1.2     0
1           0.4     0       0       0       0
2           0       0.1     0       1.4     0.5
3          -0.1    -0.2     0.1     1.1     0.1

and bias = 1, then the components of problem are:

l = 5
n = 6

y -> 1 2 1 2 3

x -> [ ] -> (2,0.1) (3,0.2) (6,1) (-1,?)
     [ ] -> (2,0.1) (3,0.3) (4,-1.2) (6,1) (-1,?)
     [ ] -> (1,0.4) (6,1) (-1,?)
     [ ] -> (2,0.1) (4,1.4) (5,0.5) (6,1) (-1,?)
     [ ] -> (1,-0.1) (2,-0.2) (3,0.1) (4,1.1) (5,0.1) (6,1) (-1,?)
```

so, seems I can't use directly a matrix and, instead, I have to make this big linked list of feature_node; Doesn't exist an easier system or any example s.t. I can do this in a easier way?

Comment: No, there is no other way. If you don't want to be limited by the types imposed by LIBSVM, then either (i) don't use C/C++ or (ii) modify the source to take some object you prefer dealing with. I don't recommend option (ii).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the documentation has changed since you posted this, but I've used an approach shown on another question [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293332/how-to-create-training-data-for-libsvm-as-an-svm-node-struct)] where I load the problem values into a matrix like so, rather than re-writing my input file to match the format. (I'm parsing the file line by line and splitting on commas, then storing in a 2d array called myData):

```
struct svm_problem prob;
struct svm_node *x_space;

prob.l = problemSize;

svm_node** x = Malloc(svm_node*, prob.l);

for (int row = 0; row < prob.l; row++)
{
    svm_node* x_space = Malloc(svm_node,4);
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
    {
        x_space[col].index = col;
        x_space[col].value = myData[row][col];
    }
    x_space[4].index = -1;
    x[row] = x_space;
}

prob.x = x;
```

It seems to work well, at least for my needs. I'm not too clear on whether this solves your issue or not (a few years too late perhaps).

Hopefully might be of use to others too.

Answer (score 0):

To those who get stuck here, index should start from 1. So it should be:

```
x_space[col].index = col + 1;
```

This is for liblinear, I am not sure whether libsvm has the same format.